# Postfix in Modoboa installation Recipient address rejected: undeliverable address: mail for example.com loops back

Tags: postfix-mta

I have just installed Modoboa with Postfix on a Ubuntu 20.04 VPS and although I have no issues sending emails, I do have a problem with inbound emails as they are rejected as undeliverable as follows:

```
mail postfix/smtpd[45105]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-0301.mail-europe.com[188.165.51.139]: 550 5.1.1 <user@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: undeliverable address: mail for example.com loops back to myself; from=<user@anotherdomain.com> to=<user@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-0301.mail-europe.com>
```

The relevant part of the config file for Postfix (main.cf) is:

```
# This file was automatically installed on 2021-09-03T08:26:48.307510
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
#myhostname = mail.example.com
myorigin = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
biff = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

The domain's MX records are set correctly: POINTS TO: mail.example.com PRIORITY:  10

If I enter: "postconf | grep myhostname" I get the following response:

```
lmtp_lhlo_name = $myhostname
local_transport = local:$myhostname
milter_macro_daemon_name = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname
myhostname = mail.example.com
myorigin = $myhostname
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_proxy_ehlo = $myhostname
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the settings that eventually worked for me:

```
myhostname = mail.example.com
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname
```